# nested angular directive not getting the correct scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I downloaded an angular directive called abn_tree to build a filesystem view in angular.

The abn_tree is nested within another directive.
My template structure which contains the directives looks like this

```
<div class=resizable-sideways" ng-controller="FileSystem">
    <abn-tree tree-data="explorer" on-select="treeSelected(branch)"></abn-tree>
</div>
```

In the initial div, `resizable-sideways` is a directives. 
In my `FileSystem` controller, I set the data of explorer, but when I view the scope of abn-tree, in the console, it says `treeData=undefined`.

The abn_tree definition is,

```
   restrict: 'E',
templateUrl: 'vendor/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/dist/abn_tree_template.html',
scope: {
  treeData: '=',
  onSelect: '&',
  initialSelection: '='
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
```

However, if I change the  html structure and remove the `resizable-sideways` directive, everything works fine.

I define resizable-sideways as

```
return {
        restrict: 'CA',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="favor-resizable-container"><div class="favor-resizable-container-wrapper" ng-transclude></div><div class="favor-resizable-bar"></div></div>',
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
```

I use resizable-sideways to wrap content in a resizable div. My guess is that the scope of abn-tree is being set to resizable-sideways when the abn-tree tag is wrapped. 
Is there a way to make sure that resizable-sideways always passes it's parent scope along to child elements, until a new scope is defined?

It may seem overly complicated, but I'm trying to create a very modular app where users can decide which features they want included, and therefore, I can't say with absolute certainty, what the parent scope should be. So hopefully, there is a way for me to set resizable to either not have a scope, inherit it's parents scope (which I thought was the default), or some other solution.

Also strangely, adding the `ng-controller` directly to the `abn-tree` tag, doesn't help either.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Prior to 1.2?   (and if it is pre-1.2, is switching to a newer version an option?)

Comment: I'm on 1.2.5, so shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Transclude changes the scope that the transcluded elements see.  [Angular guide to directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> The transclude option changes the way scopes are nested. It makes it
>   so that the **contents of a transcluded directive have whatever scope is
>   outside the directive, rather than whatever scope is on the inside**. In
>   doing so, it gives the contents access to the outside scope.

You can see how this plays out [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mG589/5/).  You'll see that resizable has scope 3 with a parent scope 2.  While abn has scope 5, parent 4, grand parent 2.  The key is that abn does not have scope 3, that the `ngController` is on in it's inheritance chain.  That's because the transcluded scope has "whatever scope is
outside the directive".

One solution is to make `ngController` a parent to both:

```
<div ng-controller="FileSystem">
   <div class="resizable-sideways">
     <abn-tree tree-data="explorer" on-select="treeSelected(branch)"></abn-tree>
   </div>
</div>
```

or you don't really need transclude for what you're doing.  Instead you can use jQlite `wrap` and `append` on the element to modify it like this (and thus avoiding the transclude scope issue):

```
myApp.directive("resizable",function() {
            return {
        restrict: 'CA',
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
             elem.wrap('<div class="favor-resizable-container-wrapper"></div>');
             elem.append('<div class="favor-resizable-bar"></div>');
             elem.wrap('<div class="favor-resizable-container"></div>');
        ....  
    }
```

Here's a [fiddle with that mocked up](http://jsfiddle.net/mG589/3/)